# Search for documents with exactly different fields values

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm adding documents with the following strutucte

```
{
    "proposta": {
        "matriculaIndicacao": 654321,
        "filial": 100,
        "cpf": "12345678901",
        "idStatus": "3",
        "status": "Reprovada",
        "dadosPessoais": {
            "nome": "John Five",
            "dataNascimento": "1980-12-01",
            "email": "fulanodasilva@fulano.com.br",
            "emailValidado": true,
            "telefoneCelular": "11 99876-9999",
            "telefoneCelularValidado": true,
            "telefoneResidencial": "11 2211-1122",
            "idGenero": "1",
            "genero": "M"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to perform a search with multiple field values.
I can successfull search for a document with a specific cpf atribute with the following search

```
{
    "query": {
      "term" : { 
          "proposta.cpf" : "23798770823" 
      }
    }
}
```

But now I need to add an AND clause, like

```
{
  "query": {
    "term" : { 
        "proposta.cpf" : "23798770823"
        ,"proposta.dadosPessoais.dataNascimento": "1980-12-01"
    }
  }
}
```

but it's returning an error message.

P.S: If possible I would like to perform a search where if the field doesn't exist, it returns the document that matches only the proposta.cpf field.

I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to combine your constraints within a `bool/should` query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "proposta.cpf": "23798770823"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "proposta.dadosPessoais.dataNascimento": "1980-12-01"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```